# bitcoind getnewaddress: Why I can see the generated address on Blockchain.info without broadcast?

Tags: bitcoind

I have a question about bitcoind's getnewaddress command. After I generated by using the command, I can search the address on Blockchain.info. As far as I checked bitcoind's log, bitcoind did not inform about the generating new address to Bitcoin network. So I'm wondering why I can see the information on Blockchain.info. Any help will be appropriated. Thanks.

My address is this.

https://blockchain.info/address/1BKasyZAsA5F6nt7hrNTJq7KQb8rwjhVAv

(update)

I found this log. Is it broadcasting log..?

```
2014-12-23 16:56:58 keypool added key 111, size=101
2014-12-23 16:56:58 keypool reserve 11
2014-12-23 16:56:58 keypool keep 11
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the newly generated address and the corresponding blockchain.info link.

Comment: @George Kimionis Hi, updated

Comment: @George Kimionis Sorry. I updated again. I Added ~/.bitcoin/debug.log

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you notice the message on the page:

> "No transactions found for this address, it has probably not been used on the network yet."

So blockchain.info just verified that the address you searched is a valid address and gave you a message telling you that it doesn't have any record of the address being used anywhere yet. If you look into what addresses really are (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address), then you will see what I mean by "validating" the address. Essentially, there are some checksum (not exactly, but close enough to convey the point) digits put on the end to make sure everything was transposed correctly.

The log you posted is not a broadcasting log, it's just debug info recording that there was a request for a new address. You're address is not known to anyone, except to everyone since it's posted on here now. :P

Comment: "blockchain.info just verified..." Make sense! I completely understand now. Thank you so much!